# ".json" endpoint in router in Actix-Web 4

Tags: json, rest, rust, actix-web

I'm using `actix-web@v4` to set up a RESTful API, and I'd like to use the convention of `.json` at the end of an endpoint to differentiate it from html rendering. For example I currently do

```
GET 127.0.0.1/api/v1/posts
```

to render an html page that lists all the model instances, now what I want is to have this

```
GET 127.0.0.1/api/v1/posts.json
```

respond with json. But my routing config **doesn't** take this format into account. I was able to do it using queries:

```
GET 127.0.0.1/api/v1/posts?json=1
```

But it looks ugly to me and I highly prefer the `.json` one. Note that I use `NormalizePath::Trim` to force trim the trailing slash of my routes. Here's my code:

```
// routes.rs
pub fn configure(cfg: &mut web::ServiceConfig) {
    let api_scope = web::scope("/api")
        .service(web::scope("/v1")
            .route("", web::to(general::root))
            .route("/doctor", web::to(general::doctor))
            .service(web::scope("/posts").configure(posts::configure)));
        
    cfg.service(api_scope);
    cfg.route("/favicon", web::to(general::favicon));
    cfg.route("/favicon.ico", web::to(general::favicon));
    cfg.route("/favicon.png", web::to(general::favicon));
    cfg.service(web::redirect("/", "/api/v1"));
    cfg.default_service(web::to(general::not_found));
}
```

Here's the actual routed function with queries:

```
// THIS DOES NOT WORK
#[get(".json")]
async fn list_json()...

// THIS WORKS
// Slash omitted due to NormalizePath::Trim
#[get("")]
async fn list(req: HttpRequest, data: web::Data<AppState>) -> Result<HttpResponse, Error> {
    let template = &data.templates;
    let conn = &data.conn;

    // get params
    let params = web::Query::<Params>::from_query(req.query_string()).unwrap();

    let page = params.page.unwrap_or(1);
    let posts_per_page = params.posts_per_page.unwrap_or(super::DEFAULT_POSTS_PER_PAGE);
    let should_json = params.json.unwrap_or(0);

    let (posts, num_pages) = Query::find_posts_in_page(conn, page, posts_per_page)
        .await
        .expect("Cannot find posts in page");

    if should_json != 1 {
        let mut ctx = tera::Context::new();
        ctx.insert("posts", &posts);
        ctx.insert("page", &page);
        ctx.insert("posts_per_page", &posts_per_page);
        ctx.insert("num_pages", &num_pages);

        let body = template
            .render("index.html.tera", &ctx)
            .map_err(|_| error::ErrorInternalServerError("Template error"))?;
        Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().content_type("text/html").body(body))
    } else {
        Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(JsonGenericResponse {
            status: StatusCode::OK.as_u16(),
            message: posts
        }))
    }
}
```

I've also tried using `cfg.route(".json", handler)` with no success.